# What underlying semantic notions connect the Latin for '(from then) to this hour' to the French « encore »?

Tags: etymology, vulgar-latin, french

> [ [CNRTL :](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/encore) ]  Du lat[in] vulg[aire] **hinc ha (c) hora* ou **hinc ad horam*;
>   la forme a[ncienne] fr[ançaise] *uncore*, *oncore* est due à l'infl[uence] de *onque*, *onc**.
>   <sub>[This thread](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/17180/1995) redirects you to the elongations of the the abbreviations used above.</sub>
>
> [ [Etymonline :](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/encore) ]  
>   [...]   French *encore* "**[3.]** still, **[4.]** yet, **[5.]** again, **[6.]** also, **[7.]** furthermore" (12c.), generally explained as being from Vulgar Latin phrase
>       **[1.]** **hinc ad horam* "from then to this hour," or
>   **[2.]** *(in) hanc horam* "(to) this hour"  [...]

I can conceive how 1 and 2 shifted semantically to mean 3. For example, a Roman may complain about how a problem has not been resolved from then (when the problem started) to this hour: i.e. how it has STILL not been resolved.

But what underlying semantic notions connect 1-2 to 3-7?

Comment: «still hasn't been resolved» = «hasn't been resolved yet», and there goes 4 :).

Comment: Btw, same question applies to "ancora" in Italian.

Comment: Also, notice how «even better», for example, can be phrased as «better still».

Answer (score 3):

In Czech, we have the word "ještě" with the same three primary meanings:

> 1) (not) yet (ještě tu není - il n'est pas encore ici - he is still
>   not here)
>
> 2) again (ještě jednou - encore une fois - one more time)
>
> 3) even more (je ještě větší - il est encore plus grand - he is even
>   taller)

The underlying meaning is some sort of continuation - "he is still not here" means that the condition of the person not being here continues. "one more time" also implies continuing what happened. "Even more" again continues some sort of a scale or progression.

Actually English "yet" has fairly similar meanings too:

> 1) He has not come yet.
>
> 2) The workers went to the factory early and are striking yet.‎
>
> 3) K-2 is yet higher than this.‎

Of course not all of these meanings were likely to be present in the original hinc-ad-horam, however it is unlikely there was no word with similar meaning in late Latin / early French (something from Latin, e.g. *usque* comes to mind, preserved in French *jusque* < *inde usque* - btw. also a cognate of Czech *ještě*), with which the new formation become synonymous and whose other meanings it might have easily adopted.